# Batch scripts with SQL output

Tags: batch-file

we tried to create one output file(SQL.txt) by calling the one SQL file in batch fils, it got succeed then tried to assign the particular value from particular line in the output file(SQL.txt) using FOR /f command to variable, and based on that we try to put a IF condition with variable value. thing is when we acho the variable value its showing the value and also showing the below lines. Because of that, IF condition is not working.

see my query below in details.

```
1) call sqlplus username/pwd@schema @D:\SQL\REORG_DATA.sql >D:\SQL\SQL_OUTPUT\output.txt
2)  for /f "skip=14 delims=5" %%n in (D:\SQL\SQL_OUTPUT\output.txt) do  echo %%n 
3) if %%n EQU 0 goto ErrExit
```

my output file is always same below is output file information

we want to capture the 0(zero) value into the IF condition as a variable value(%%n), it always 15th line and 6 dlims

```
1
2 SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Feb 23 14:17:56 2015
3
4 Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
5
6
7 Connected to:
8 Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
9 With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
10 Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
11
12
13  COUNT(*)
14 ----------
15      0
16
17 Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
18 With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
19 Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
20
```

please help on the same.

Regards 
Nag

Answer (score 0):

```dos
set "count="
for /f "skip=14" %%n in (
    D:\SQL\SQL_OUTPUT\output.txt
) do if not defined count set "count=%%n"

echo %count%
```

`delims` defines what characters are used as delimiters. The default configuration is spaces and tabs, so, there is no need to include it.

The element in the line that you need to retrieve is controlled by the `tokens` clause, but the default configuration is to retrieve the first one, that is what you need, so, it is also not needed.

Now, you skip 14 lines and retrieve the first element in the line. But you only need to retrieve data for the first processed line. But the `do` clause is executed for the rest of the lines, reassigning the variable. You can include a `goto` to leave the loop or test if the variable has been assigned a value.

**edited** to include a sample using the `goto` command

```dos
    set "count="
    for /f "skip=14" %%n in (D:\SQL\SQL_OUTPUT\output.txt) do set "count=%%n" & goto :done
:done
    echo %count%
```

Comment: Thanks for your information, I have followed as you said and also tried to put the goto command for exit from loop but it is still reassign the remaining line to count variable and I need exactly single line value, could you please tell how to put goto command after the assign the single value.  set "count="
for /f "skip=14" %%n in (D:\SLB\APP\Hyperion\Automations\SQL\SQL_OUTPUT\output.txt) do goto eof "count=%%n" 
 
echo %count%    I have used above code to leave the loop.

Comment: @NAG, answer updated to include the code with a `goto`

Comment: I'd suggest that if the value on the 15th line is always numeric, a `set /a count=%%n` would be preferable.

Comment: @Magoo, why? i see no advantage (the spaces are removed as delimiters) but there is a cost as the `set /a` invokes its own parser to handle arithmetics. And at the end both `set` commands will store the data as string in the environment. What am i missing here?  What am i not seeing?

Comment: Yeah - you're right. Just saw the quotes and assumed a string assignment

Comment: Thanks for you assist, that code working fine. we are new to this language.                                                                                               we need one more help from you, this about How to send a email to users after executed scripts.                                                                                                          And also could you please tell us how to configure the mail server in the batch files                                                                                                                                 Thanks